# C# Extension methods for Existing methods

Tags: c#, .net

How can I write an extension method for an existing method like :

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void RunAsThread(this Action func)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            try
            {
                if (func != null)
                    func();
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException tie) { }
            catch (ThreadAbortException tae) { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogDebug(ex);
            }
        });
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

is there any way that i can run this methods perfectly in the way i wanted

```
class WorkingClass
{
    public void Work()
    {
        //Works fine
        ((Action)DoSomething).RunAsThread();

        //Works fine
        Extensions.RunAsThread(DoSomething);

        //But I really need this to work
        DoSomething.RunAsThread();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

I really wanted to make DoSomething.RunAsThread() work.
I tried to change "static void RunAsThread(this delegate .... or this Delegate)".
Could not do it properly.
Is there any work around for that? Is there any way for that?

Comment: No, you can't do this. `DoSomething` isn't an `Action`. In certain contexts, the compiler can create an `Action` from it, but this isn't one of those contexts.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this, as `DoSomething` is not a type, it's a method.

Also, just because you can attach an extension method to a type it doesn't mean you should..!

Answer (score 1):

If `DoSomething` doesn't *have* to be an actual method, a slight tweak would make this compile:

```
class WorkingClass
{
    public void Work()
    {
        //Works fine
        ((Action)DoSomething).RunAsThread();

        //Works fine
        Extensions.RunAsThread(DoSomething);

        //But I really need this to work
        DoSomething.RunAsThread();
    }

    private Action DoSomething = () =>
    {
        //Do Something
    };
}
```

Whether that fits in with everything else you're writing or not, I couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

`DoSomething` is just a "Method group" it will be implicitly converted to `Action` or compatible delegate type whenever possible.

`DoSomething` itself not a `Delegate`, so **not possible**. but you could do the following with the help of implicit method group conversion.

```
Action a = DoSomething;
a.RunAsThread();
```